# Database versioning tool for Node and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-migration

Is there a solution that helps you manage database schema patches, preferably that runs in Node. I am looking at node-db-migrate which has support for MySQL but I want to be able to run plain vanilla SQL on it instead of using wrapper functions offered by this package.

Is there a solution that offers the same functionality but also lets you have plain SQL in patches?

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally a fan of Sequelize, which has a (poorly named) sister project called Umzug designed to handle migrations. You can absolutely run vanilla SQL in a package like this, but be very careful doing so. Running raw SQL can be an easy way to do something like populate a new column with data (perhaps a new summary column that needs to be filled with the results of a more complex query you've been running until now). However, it can also make it very easy to make mistakes if you do this for things like `ALTER TABLE`. Whenever you can, it's best to use provided constructs for things like that.